# How to convert html to plain text in angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

I am using ng-bind-html (with ngSanitize module) to display html as plain text in view. It is tied to the scope variable partyinfo.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" ng-bind-html="partyinfo" contenteditable="false"></div>
```

How can I look at the same scope variable and convert to plain text on the controller side? Is there an equivalent way of doing ng-bind-html on controller side?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `convert to plain text on the controller side` `doing ng-bind-html on controller side` you're asking for two opposite things, which one do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question but you could try with `$sanitize` service:

```
$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.partyInfo);
```